# Emitting 2 observables, processing the result and then emitting another one

Tags: java, node.js, java-8, rx-java, vert.x

I have the following task to perform:

I need to emit 2 observables (obs1 & obs2) process their results and then call another observable (obs3) and process its results and if possible that while processing the results of obs3 have access to the results of obs1 and obs2.

This is my draft code which doesn't do the trick, how can I alter it.

```
public void executeFind(String session_id, long template_id, GameModelType game_model) {

   Observable<RxMessage<byte[]>> userObs = context.getUser(session_id);
   Observable<Game> gameObs = context.findGame(template_id, game_model, GameStateType.WAITING);

   Observable.zip(userObs, gameObs, new Func2<RxMessage<byte[]>, Game, GameObject>() {

     @Override
     public GameObject call(RxMessage<byte[]> userRawReply, ActiveGame game) {

     ..
     ..
     return context.updateGame(game.getGameData())
            .subscribe(new Action1<GameObject>() {

                @Override
                public void call(GameObject updateReply) {
                    ..
                    ..

                }
            });

        return userReply; 
     }
   });
 }
```

This doesn't really work - I can write a code which uses explicit calls to .flatMap\subscribe for each Observable but results in many nested calls which is obviously poor usage of the framework.

What is the right way to solve this??

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I've found this solution to work, but I'm still wondering whether there is a "cleaner" way to achieve this:

```
public void executeFind(ReplyMessage<JsonObject> replyObj, String session_id, long template_id,     GameModelType game_model) throws CommandException {

    rx.Observable<GameObject> userObs = context.getUser(session_id);
    rx.Observable<Game> gameObs = context.findGame(template_id, game_model, GameStateType.WAITING);

    rx.Observable.zip(userObs, gameObs, new Func2<GameObject, Game, List<Object>>() {

        @Override
        public List<Object> call(GameObject userReply, Game game) {

            User user = ...;

            final List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>(3); 
            results.add(ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK);
            results.add(user);
            results.add(game);


            context.updateGame(game.getGameData()).subscribe(new Action1<GameObject>() {

                @Override
                public void call(GameObject updateReply) {

                    ...
                }

            });


            return results;
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<List<Object>>() {

        @Override
        public void call(List<Object> results) {

            int status = (int) results.get(0);
            User user = (User) results.get(1);
            Game game = (Game) results.get(2);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: It's [unclear](http://sscce.org/) what you trying to achieve. Zip was intentionally removed from stream api so may be you need to rethink the what problem you trying to solve.

Comment: please take a look at my "EDIT" - it may be clearer now. if you have better solution .. please share....

Comment: Again, to me it's like you have OOD problem. You ziping random gameObjects and userObjects, later of which suddenly becomes userReply. Then you get user and keep draging things further. Some things are [meant to be together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 1):

I would code this thing with the following idea in mind. May be `map` can be replace with `flatMap` if that's relevant for your use case. Also note I have only used Java 8 lambdas syntax, but for more readability I strongly advises you to have simple and well named methods (and use them with a method reference) for each of these functions/actions as it will raise understandability of the code *(That's what we do on mockito, but everyone should do it in their own code base)*.

```
public void executeFind(ReplyMessage<JsonObject> reply_obj, String session_id, long template_id,     GameModelType game_model) throws CommandException {
    Observable<GameObject> userObs = context.getUser(session_id);
    Observable<Game> gameObs = context.findGame(template_id, game_model, GameStateType.WAITING);
    Observable.zip(userObs, gameObs, (userReply, game) -> {
        User user = ...;
        return GameOfUser.gameFound(game, user);
    }).map(gou -> { 
        context.updateGame(gou.gameData()).susbcribe(...);
        return gou;
    }).subscribe(gou -> ...);
}
```

Comment: GameOfUser that you created is like a wrapper for 'game' and 'user' and it returns an Observable that late can be mapped and subscribed. Have I goten it right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. Still feel free to explore further. Note that the rxjava mailing list is a good place to ask too. Some people follows both SO and the mailing list.

Comment: Coming to think about your solution, it's not whole different than what I suggested, no?? my solution builds a list and pass it to subscribe.

Comment: yes, indeed, it's similar in approach, I don't know the requirement you have to deal with. But the flow is more Rx than your snippet. So I think that's the cleaner way you may want ...according to the ;)